# WSO2 Enterprise Integrator 6.5.0 - Removing XML tag in SOAP messages

Tags: xml, soap, wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator

I am calling a SOAP endpoint from my WSO2 enterprise integrator project using the following code:

```
 <payloadFactory media-type="xml">
    <format>
        <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ws="http://ws.test.com/">
            <soapenv:Header/>
            <soapenv:Body>
                <ws:process>
                    <request>
                        <action>$1</action>
                        <transaction>
                            <id>$2</id>
                        </transaction>
                    </request>
                </ws:process>
            </soapenv:Body>
        </soapenv:Envelope>
    </format>
    <args>
        <arg evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('ACTION')"/>
        <arg evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('TRANSACTION_ID')"/>
    </args>
</payloadFactory>
<property name="messageType" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="application/soap+xml"/>
<log level="full"/>
<call-template target="do_call"/>
```

And in the template the code is as follows:

```
  <call>
        <endpoint>
            <address format="soap11" uri="${uri.var.url}"/>
        </endpoint>
    </call>
```

WSO2 is auto generating   at the beginning of the message. and it is causing issues with the endpoint. How can i prevent this?
I tried to remove the message type, or change it to text/xml but it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

In your PayloadFactory just have the message body.

```xml
<payloadFactory media-type="xml">
   <format>
         <ws:process>
             <request>
                 <action>$1</action>
                 <transaction>
                     <id>$2</id>
                 </transaction>
             </request>
         </ws:process>
   </format>
   <args>
       <arg evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('ACTION')"/>
       <arg evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('TRANSACTION_ID')"/>
   </args>
</payloadFactory>
```

Then in your endpoint send it as a Soap Message, you can specify the SOAP version that the backend supports. `soap11` or `soap12`, note that the content type `application/soap+xml` is for `soap12`.

```xml
 <call>
    <endpoint>
        <address format="soap11" uri="${uri.var.url}"/>
    </endpoint>
</call>
```